# Page.User.IsInRole returned as false

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Webforms web site that includes Web API. The site is developed and tested with Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5 on Windows 8 with IIS Express as web server.
Just a little bit of background. I moved my project from an old asp.net website to a new asp.net web api enabled project by transferring the files one by one and matching up the config settings.

In my project, I'm encountering an issue with  Page.User.IsInRole which always returns false. My login method has following lines of code:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket _ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, lUserName.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), chk_remember.Checked, Role, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(_ticket);
        HttpCookie _cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
        if (chk_remember.Checked)
            _cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(_cookie);
```

Role is a string who's values is captured from the database. Page.Identity.User returns the name of the user fine but `Page.User.IsInRole("Admin");`is always returned as false. I have looked for solutions but none of the solution worked.
In my other project, I don't have this issue. What do I need to do to fix this?
Any help is appreciated!